# How many strings of n bits are there which differ by exactly m bits?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, bit-strings

For example:
If n = 8 and m = 0:  ans = 1
If n = 8 and m = 1:  ans = 8
If n = 8 and m = 2:  ans = ?
If n =256 and m = 3: ans = ?

Comment: Isn't this just $n\choose m$? Perhaps I am misinterpreting the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose the $m$ bits out of $n$ to be different, so $n \choose m$

Comment: You're right of course. Thanks!